# TCPDF awful text rendering

Tags: php, text, tcpdf

Hy,
I have some images that I converto to PDF pages with TCPDF::Image, and then I add the text on another level, but the results I get rendering text with TCPDF are quite awful, this is how the text should look
[image]
And this is the rendered PDF 
[image]
As you can see TCPDF is inserting some new line "randomly", And I can't understand why, I'm using tcpdf 6.2.6
this is my code

```
 $pdf->SetFont($TCPDFFontFile, $fontStyle, $fontSize, '', false);
 $pdf->setTextRenderingMode(0, true);
 $pdf->setCellHeightRatio($lineHeight);                             
 $pdf->SetTextColorArray($textColorArray);
 $pdf->MultiCell(
     $removedItem->width,
     $removedItem->height,
     $removedItem->text,
     0,
     $textAlign,
     false,
     1,
     $left,
     $right
 );
```

Any ideas? Maybe a problem with the latest version? Even if I already tried with many other version like 6.1.0 or 6.2.0 but nothing changed...

**EDIT:** I noticed that there are differences even in the charater spacing, and even the height of the lines are slithly different, is this any help?

Comment: This *may* be overthinking it, but it's how I tackled a similar situation a while ago. Convert the PDF (that you want to import) to an image using GhostScript, then import the image into TCPDF using [TCPDF::Image](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352).... probably overthinking it and doesn't allow edits to imported PDF. - But it worked for me (as I didn't need to edit the original PDF)

Comment: sorry, my fault, I wasn't clear explaining, I already do this, I import some images and convert them into pdf, Adding the text on top. I'll edit my question, thank's